# Critical Damping

Tags: calculus

The angle $A$ of a heavily damped swinging door varies with time according to the law:

$$ A(t) = \frac{e^{-at} - e^{-bt}}{b-a}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants that depend on the damping, the weight of the door, and the spring.

The variable $t$ is measured in seconds, and $A$ is the angle in radians.

When $b=a$, the damping is said to be "critical"; how does $A$ then depend on $t$?

Comment: b=a implies b-a=0 a division by 0 error occurs.

Comment: I know that the result is undefined when b = a, but the question is given in this form i am stuck!!

Comment: Do you know the definition of a derivative? As @RoddyMacPhee said, you end up dividng by $0$ when $a = b$, but you can consider $\lim_{a \to b}$.

Comment: you also get 0 on top. but limits was my thought as well.

Comment: 0/0 is indeterminate so you mean that i can apply LHospital's rule??

Comment: You could use L'Hopital's rule, but I think it's better practice to think about the definition of the derivative. Let $f(x) = e^{-xt}$. Then $A(t) = -\frac{f(a) - f(b)}{a - b}$. Critical damping is then given by $A(t) = - \lim_{a \to b} \frac{f(a) - f(b)}{ a - b}$. This limit is, by definition, $f'(b)$. At this point, I've pretty much completely given the problem away, so I'm just going to post a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f(x) = e^{-xt}$. Then
$$
A(t) = \frac{f(a) - f(b)}{b -a} = -\frac{f(a) - f(b)}{a - b}
$$
As has been pointed out, if $a = b$, the expression is undefined. But, if we instead consider $\lim_{a \to b}$, we get a definite answer. In the limit, critical damping is given by
$$
A_{crit}(t) = -\lim_{a \to b} \frac{f(a) - f(b)}{a - b} = - f'(b) = te^{-bt}
$$